# Expression for random normal error

Tags: r, random, normal-distribution

Here they use `ei` to denote the random normal error, can any one explain why they use:

```
rnorm(length(xi),0,1)
```

to express this:

```
ei = rnorm(length(xi),0,1)
yi = sin(2*pi*xi)+ei
```

Comment: Please see [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the documentation for [rnorm](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/Normal.html), we can use that to explain your statement:

```
ei = rnorm(length(xi),0,1)
```

- `length(xi)` because you want an error term for each observation.
- `0,1` because you want the errors to be random normal (mean 0, standard deviation 1)

Hope this helps.